# Order VARCHAR field by custom order in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table field called "ApDay VARCHAR(15)" which contains Days of Week. I want to sort the table values according to the ApDay field. That means i want to sort results according to the days of week. But i want to sort them to a custom order. Which means the "Saturday" should come first then other like "sunday,monday,..." so on. I am using entity framework. Can any one plese tell me how to achieve this using entity framework and C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can translate your AppDay field with **CASE** in sql according your desired order and then order by that field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define an enum as below

```
public enum Day
{
    Sunday =0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday =3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6
}
```

Then you can prepare ordered list by AppDay as below.

```
var orderedList = myTableData.OrderByDescending(x => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Day), x.AppDay, true));
```